# Using flow to annotate a function that accepts another function

Tags: flowtype

I understand the basic rules for annotating a function definition, e.g. if you want to assert that the first argument should always be a string, etc.

But what if you want to assert that the first argument should be *another function*? (Also, is it possible to specify what *signature* the passed function should have?)

I have attempted to work this out from the [flow docs on functions](https://flowtype.org/docs/functions.html) but I am very confused, and some examples would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks something like this:

```
function myFunction(fn: (foo: string, bar: number) => Array<string>) {
}
```